# Untangling large nested if else code structures in C# with a tool like Resharper etc

Tags: c#, if-statement, refactoring

**Update : The actual code is 300 lines , at places 7 levels deep, if you don't know how to flatten a deeply nested if else structure move on to other questions else if you know then answer this else if.**

I have inherited a large nested if else structure, I am trying to separate the leaves of the if else tree into separate if statements only e.g. :

```
if ( c1 )
  { dc1 }
else if ( c2 )
          { dc2 }
     else {dc3}
```

should become something like :

```
if (c1) {dc1;}

if ((!c1) & (c2)) {dc2;}

if ((!c1) & (!c2)) {dc3;}
```

**This example is much simpler than the unholy structure I need to untangle.**

Side question : it easy to see that there is no condition that takes into account the case

```
if ((c1) & (c2))
```

is there a tool or simpler way of linearising the if else structures and seeing all the conditions that have not been included.

I hope my example is correct.

Comment: Some tools like Resharper can help you with it - invert conditions, rearrange them, but most work will be anyway done by you. Many ifs in one method is a smell of bad architecture and rearranging your conditions will not help with it - you need to review your code, split your conditions into smaller methods, classes, according to your logic.

Comment: Honestly, I don't see a difference between the two, except that the original has less logic in it. An alternative might be a `case` statement, which might work a little more in favour of what you're attempting to achieve?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev : this is the case deciding what to do , there are 20+ variables that their state is used to determine what needs to be done, I am trying to simplify that , put some order into them, as it is I cant see where does the if part of an statement starts.

Comment: @Ben : I take a case statement over a deeply neseted if else any days, mu example is only one level deep, the code I am trying to fix is at some points 7 levels deep.

Comment: decompile the assembly and the code should be well formatted.

Comment: @LeiYang : This is genius, Thank you.

Comment: @Arjang You can do Crtl+K/Ctrl+D to format document directly in VS. There's no need to hop through a decompilation. And don't forget, decompilation **will** include all compiler generated classes. There will be no possible way to compile it again if you have used anything like iterators, lambda expressions, async (I don't think your codebase would have that given the problem) etc.

Comment: @TanveerBadar : Is that going to linearise a nested if else code structure? or just format it to a pretty shape.

Comment: Only format it, compiler will not transform your code in that manner anyway. And the formatting will be done by decompiler to assist the user. Compiler does not care about whitespace in majority of cases. Do you wish to discuss this further on chat?

Comment: @TanveerBadar : Thank you, just finished a 12 hour day, I'll manage this another way (hint Roslyn! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would advice against that for a few reasons.

1. Do you have tests written against that particular piece of code to
   ensure nothing breaks after this refactoring. It is called
   refactoring what you are trying to do here.
2. Consider the following code as a counter example.

   ```
   if( c1 )
   {
        if( c2 )
        {
             if( c3 )
             {
             }
             else
             {
             }
         }
         else
         {
              if( c4 )
              {
              }
         }
   }
   else
   {
         if( !c5 )
        {
        }
    }
   ```

As written, I think this code is fairly understandable. Refactoring it to flatten the condition tree will only make them harder to understand for maintainers.

3. Depending on your language, such if/else blocks or switch/case equally usually mean someone bungled up the design if it supports OOP particularly if they are operating on type flags.

Regarding Tests

Those 2^5 conditions you mentioned earlier. You really need some tools to assist you before you undertake this refactoring. If your conditions are something combinatorial then perhaps some sort of test generator will make sense. You will also need to get your hands on a good code coverage tool to ensure you leave no code path untested. Only then you can be sure that you have left nothing uncovered.

Comment: You need 8 spaces if the code is in an (un)ordered list. Fixed.

Comment: @Sweeper Thank you very much for helping me out with this!

Comment: so just by looking at this you can tell if all the 2^5 possibilities of conditions have been taken into account?

Comment: Perhaps. That depends on what one is trying to do really. And visual inspection is a very poor tool to ascertain correctness anyway. When in doubt, write tests.

Comment: I'll amend my answer to your question since comments do no have enough space.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know what you are trying to do, because this:

```
if ( c1 )
  { dc1 }
else if ( c2 )
          { dc2 }
     else {dc3}
```

Isn't really a deeply nested structure. Look, if you just change the formatting a little bit:

```
if (c1)
{
    dc1
}
else if (c2)
{
    dc2
}
else
{
    dc3
}
```

This is very readable. You are checking for 3 conditions. If this is true, do this, if that is true, do that. Deep nesting would look something like this:

```
if (c1) {
    dc1
    if (c2) {
        dc2
        if (c3) {
            dc3
        }
    }
}
```

So my advice is: the current code looks fine. You just need to add/remove whitespace at appropriate places so that it looks clean, like the sample I showed here.

On the other hand, this:

```
if (c1) {dc1;}

if ((!c1) & (c2)) {dc2;}

if ((!c1) & (!c2)) {dc3;}
```

is less readable. It'll take more time for people to understand what `!c1 && c2` means. You have `else` statements to use. They are designed for this kind of situation.

Comment: As I said the code is deeply nested, my example is much simpler than the actual code.

Comment: Then show the actual code, or something more similar to it, so that we know what kind of structure you are dealing with here. At the moment I can't see deep nesting in your code. @Arjang

Comment: do you reallywant me to paste 300 lines of company code here :)
The example is to show what the end result I want is to be.

Comment: If your code's structure is something like the first code block in your question, then you don't have deep nesting.  If you want to get your current code to have a structure like the first code block, then you need to show the current structure. Also, there is also the possibility that this is an XY problem and what you need is not to fix the structure but to introduce a new method or class, in which case you need to show some of your code's contents, not just structure, in order for us to help you. @Arjang

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have no idea what I was thinking, thank you

Comment: do you have 300 lines in the single method?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to break the code into several methods handling different conditions. That would help you to understand the code easily in future.

Comment: That is why I asked this question!